# Does SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR do anything on Windows 10

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, pthreads

I've spent some time optimizing a multi-threaded application under Ubuntu 16.04 (using the pthread library). In the end I got the best performance by explicitly setting the scheduling and priority thread attributes to a combination of `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR` at varying priorities between `sched_get_priority_min()` and `sched_get_priority_max()`.

This application is also ported to Windows10 using a win32 pthread library implementation. Does the underlying OS respect these 'real-time' scheduling policies? Or in other words, does specifying them actually do anything under Windows10?

Comment: Can't directly answer your question, but in my test, even as administrator, pthread_attr_setschedpolicy() returned some error code when called with SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR. The same test code worked well on Linux.